# Retrieve the model and controller in dll file from publish project ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, publish

Is there a way to restore the model and controller from the dll file in the published project? I accidentally undo all the changes from my local project and I don't have a backup from it and the other way to retrieve all the changes that I made is to get the production file but the only thing I can retrieve is all the Views folder and other files except for the model and controller. I have a huge update from this project :'( Please help me.

[image]

Comment: You mean you made the change to code, and deploy to production without committing the changes to the source control?

Comment: That's right :(

Comment: I think the first thing you need to work is to move away from deploying uncommitted code to production environment. You can use dotPeek tool (https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to decompile the DLL and recover the code.